the natural morphism to the image is epic
So this is about abelian categories. Given a morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$, by the universal property of the cokernel of $f$ we find a morphism $f':A\rightarrow \mathrm{im}(f)=\ker(\mathrm{coker}(f))$. My question is, if this is an epic in the categorical sense. I would assume so from my intuition from rings and groups, but I can not prove it. Any help is apprechiated!

There are several equivalent ways to define an abelian category. One of those definitions explicitly requires that the canonical morphism $ \varphi: \mathrm{coim} (f) \rightarrow \mathrm{im} (f) $ is an isomorphism. Here $ \mathrm{coim} (f) = \mathrm{coker} \left( \mathrm{ker} (f) \right) $; it is a good exercise to convince yourself why the universal properties of kernel and cokernel promise that your morphism $f'$ is in fact the composition $ A \rightarrow \mathrm{coim} (f) \xrightarrow{\varphi} \mathrm{im} (f) $. After you prove this, since $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, you just have to show that $ A \rightarrow \mathrm{coim} (f) $ is epic. This follows from the fact that every cokernel is epic (a fairly straightforward exercise using the universal property of cokernel).
